# Adding a scoring profile with the .NET client

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I can't find how to use the .NET Client for Azure search to add a scoring profile. Yes, I know [there's a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index) to do it using the REST API
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scoring profiles have to be created at the same time as the index:

```
private async Task CreateIndexAsync<T>(string index) where T : class
{
    var definition = new Index()
    {
       Name = index,
       Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<T>(),
       ScoringProfiles = new List<ScoringProfile>
       {
           //your scoring profiles here
       }
   };

   if (!_adminServiceClient.Indexes.Exists(index))
   {
       await _adminServiceClient.Indexes.CreateAsync(definition);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `v11` of Azure search library for `.Net` you can add scoring profile to the search index like this:

```
var fieldBuilder = new FieldBuilder();
var searchFields = fieldBuilder.Build(typeof(MyType));
var definition = new SearchIndex(name: "MyIndexName", searchFields);

definition.ScoringProfiles.Add(new ScoringProfile(name: "default")
{
  // Your scoring profile definition
}

await _searchIndexClient.CreateIndexAsync(definition);
```